# Printing instances of class through inherited method

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to do some simple stuff with OOP and Python, building some simple books service. I am trying to create class for Books, where each object will be a Book with attributes, that works, it is not the best, but good enough for now.

```py
# Definition of class
class Books(object):

    book_id = ""
    book_title = ""
    book_author = ""
    book_year = ""
    book_pub = ""
    book_ac = ""
    book_date = ""
    Books = [book_id, book_title, book_author,
             book_year, book_pub, book_ac, book_date]

    # Set constructor
    def __init__(self, book_id, book_title, book_author, book_year, book_pub, book_ac, book_date):
        self.book_id = book_id
        self.book_title = book_title
        self.book_author = book_author
        self.book_year = book_year
        self.book_pub = book_pub
        self.book_ac = book_ac
        self.book_date = book_date

    # Set attributes
    def set_book_id(self, book_id):
        self.book_id = book_id

    def set_book_title(self, book_title):
        self.book_title = book_title

    def set_book_author(self, book_author):
        self.book_author = book_author

    def set_book_year(self, book_year):
        self.book_year = book_year

    def set_book_pub(self, book_pub):
        self.book_pub = book_pub

    def set_book_ac(self, book_ac):
        self.book_ac = book_ac

    def set_book_date(self, book_date):
        self.book_date = book_date

    # Show attributes
    def show_book_id(self):
        print(self.book_id)

    def show_book_title(self):
        print(self.book_title)

    def show_book_author(self):
        print(self.book_author)

    def show_book_year(self):
        print(self.book_year)

    def show_book_pub(self):
        print(self.book_pub)

    def show_book_ac(self):
        print(self.book_ac)

    def show_book_date(self):
        print(self.book_date)

    # Show book
    def show_book(self):
        print(self.book_id)
        print(self.book_title)
        print(self.book_author)
        print(self.book_year)
        print(self.book_pub)
        print(self.book_ac)
        print(self.book_date)
```

Second Class is Booklist, which should hold the books inside and manage books inside, I am trying to create some basic methods as to create objects in Booklist automatically as I create Books object(this should work). Then I would like to operate with Booklist as with inherited methods from Books class to show the Books or etc.

```py
# Definition of class


class BookList(Books):

    listbook = []

    # Set constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.listbook = []

    # Add book
    def add_book(self, Books):
        return self.listbook.append(Books)

    # Show book
    def show_books(self):
        for b in self.listbook:
            super().show_book(self)

    # Search book
    def search_book_by_id(self):
        self.listbook = []
        for Books in self.book_id:
            if Books.book_id == id:
                id.append(Books)
        return id
```

Bellow are my tests, as I am still fighting with error like issues of parsing arguments-Expected one or more arguments from would anyone help here what would be the easiest please to use inherited method or to manipulate with inheritance for this use case please? Thank you

```py
# Books defining
book1 = Books('1504234', 'Murders', 'Peter Jacob',
              '2015', 'Ikaro', '5', '25.5.2015')
book2 = Books('1504231', 'Murders', 'Peter Jacob',
              '2015', 'Ikaro', '5', '25.5.2015')
book3 = Books('1504232', 'Hiden language', 'Samuel Fellow',
              '2005', 'Parik', '3', '21.4.2006')
book4 = Books('1504233', 'Saturday', 'Filp Sapko',
              '2012', 'Satik', '4', '25.3.2012')

book1.show_book()
book1.set_book_title('New Murders')
book1.show_book()
book1.show_book_ac()

print("Booklist ******************************")
BookList.listbook.append(book1)
BookList.listbook.append(book2)
BookList.listbook.append(book3)
BookList.listbook.append(book4)
```

(Until here it works)Now the issue begins:

```
 BookList.show_books()ERROR:
    TypeError: show_books() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Would anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?
Thank you very much!
Best Regards

Comment: You never create a `BookList`. You're asking the *idea* of a list to print itself out, not a specific list.

Comment: Why should BookList inherit from Books?

Comment: You and Nikola should form a study group!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73270866/how-do-i-define-a-method-to-store-a-collection-e-g-dictionary  I'd suggest to both of you that just defining `Book` as a `@dataclass` and using a regular old list for `BookList` will save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, I think you're imagining the structure of these classes a little wrong. The "Books" class shouldn't be the parent of "BookList" if you intend to use the super() method to access "show_books". Not to worry, you're almost there already

---

you only need to change it from this:

```py
#Show book
def show_books(self):
    for b in self.listbook:
        super().show_book(self)
```

to this:

```py
#Show book
def show_books(self):
    for b in self.listbook:
        b.show_book()
```

---

Your "search_book_by_id" method will also need to change from this:

```py
#Search book
def search_book_by_id(self):
    self.listbook = []
    for Books in self.book_id:
            if Books.book_id == id:
                id.append(Books)
    return id
```

to this:

```py
#Search book
def search_book_by_id(self, id):
    id_books = []
    for b in self.listbook:
        if b.book_id == id:
                id_books.append(Books)
    return id_books
```

Though I'm not sure exactly what that function was attempting before.

---

You also said you wanted the BookList class to automatically add books when you create them, there are far more complicated ways to link classes which I think you might not need, if all you need is for the Book class to live inside the BookList class, then I would suggest making a create_book function inside the BookList class that adds the book to the list once created, that way you only use one object. That would look something like this:

```py
def create_book(self,book_id,book_title,book_author,book_year,book_pub,book_ac,book_date):
    self.listbook.append(Books(book_id,book_title,book_author,book_year,book_pub,book_ac,book_date))
```

That's a pretty messy function, and you should probably look into better ways to handle objects with many attributes, checkout the @property decorator and look for other ways to store data than attributes, you can also use (*args, **kwargs) to really make things easy on the user of the function, but if you're very new to python, sometimes keeping things messy but simple is better to learn the basics with. Let me know if that helps or you need something else!

Comment: Thank you very much for you follow up and deep explanations, will have a look more in depth to understand it, but you helped a lot. Thank you @destent !

Comment: I think I got the idea of the connection between the classes, and done thinks same way you do here, only thing I miss- still receive error when calling: 
listbook= add_book('1504231','Murders','Peter Jacob','2015','Ikaro','5','25.5.2015') , which will throw error - which I quite dont get why ? listbook= add_book('1504231','Murders','Peter Jacob','2015','Ikaro','5','25.5.2015')
TypeError: add_book() missing 1 required positional argument: 'book_date'
Would you be able to help here please ? Thanks

Comment: looks like you're missing one argument when you go to define a book. but you're giving the right amount. I'm going to take a guess and say that you didn't define it within a class, or didn't instantiate the object to start with. "add_book" shouldn't be able to be called on its own unless you defined it outside the class, which you don't want to do. add_book is intended to add a book to listbook for you, so all you should have to do is this: (go to next comment)

Comment: `>book_list = BookList()`
`>book_list.add_book('1504231','Murders','Peter Jacob','2015','Ikaro','5','25.5.2015')`
`>book_list.show_book()`
`1504231`
`Murders`
`Peter Jacob`
`2015`
`Ikaro`
`5`
`25.5.2015`

Comment: That comment didn't come out very well...

Comment: Thank you, got it sorted out, had inappropriate call for method! Thank you