# How do I 'define a method to store a collection (e.g., dictionary)'?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, oop

I'm a beginner working on a library management system and there's something I can't get my head around.

So I have a Books class that creates new book records.

```
class Books:

    def __init__(self, title=None, author=None, year=None, publisher=None, num_copies=None,
                 num_available_copies=None, publication_date=None):
        self.bookID = random.randint(1, 1000)
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.year = year
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.num_copies = num_copies
        self.num_available_copies = num_available_copies
        self.publication_date = publication_date
```

I then have to define another class 'BookList' which has the following requirement: 'Define a method to store a collection (e.g., dictionary). The collection should store book instances that are created from the Book object.' How do I do that?

Comment: Why doesn't a `list` containing `Books` instances work for you?
By the way, the naming convention is for the class name to be singular as to represent the name of a single instance, so `Books` should probably be `Book`.

Comment: Ad an aside, `self.bookID = random.randint(1, 1000)` is not a reasonable way to generate IDs, at least not if you want them to be unique

Comment: @Olivier - That's the way I've been instructed to do it. Point taken on the naming convention, thanks.

Comment: Make a class like: `class BookList(list): pass`.  That meets the requirements of the assignment as you've described it.  Unless you require an interface that goes beyond what `list` provides there's no reason to actually implement anything different.

Comment: inside `BookList` use `list` to keep books - `self.books = list()` - and add some function to work with this list.

Answer (score 1):

Following your request exactly would result in this new class:

```py
class BookList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_books = []
    def add_book(self, book: Books):
        self.list_of_books.append(book)
```

This is not exactly the best way to do python. But I guess anything goes in a learning scenario. For a slightly better implementation of all of this refer to the code below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Book:
    book_id               : int
    title                 : str
    author                : str
    year                  : int
    publisher             : str
    num_copies            : int
    num_available_copies  : int
    publication_date      : int

class BookList:
    def __init__(self):
        self._books = []
    @property
    def books(self):
        return self._books
    @books.setter
    def books(self, book):
        if isinstance(book, Book):
            self._books.append(book)
```

now using it will be like this:

```
>>> book_list = BookList()
>>> book_list.books
[]
>>> book_list.add_book(Book(Bunch of parameters here))
>>> book_list.books
[Book(Parameters from the book you made)]
```

you can do a lot more than what I did, I added the properties so that if you decide to copy this code to pass some kind of school class, you'll have some explaining to do. Otherwise good luck!